# Как спарсить HTML страницу и вывести текст в div с class?

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Я находил кучу решений как спарсить на странице определённые div с class но чаще всего у меня вылезал какой то бред вместо текста внутри этих div.
Вот начальный код:

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load("https://virusscan.jotti.org/en-US/search/hash/e889544aff85ffaf8b0d0da705105dee7c97fe26");
```

Мне нужно спарсить текст в div с классом `stack-horizontally filescannerresult result-infected`

Что бы не только один, а все с этим классом вывелись. 
Помогите пожалуйста!!

Добавлено: всё таки можно и один обьект с таким классом. Но лучше сразу 
все.

UPD: Алло! Там нет ответа! Мне нужно именно текст между всеми div с определённым class. Мда... Ну спасибо!

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что вопрос не дубликат? Последняя правка не совсем понятна.

Comment: Потому что на вопрос, которым меня пометили дубликатом, не было ответа на мою проблему. Там был ответ только как выделить href внутри тэга "a". А мне нужно вывести ТЕКСТ внутри тега DIV с определённым классом.

Comment: @SharpPythoneist, день добрый. Вопросы по подходу идентичны. Вы можете понять подход из дубликата и применить к своей задаче. Иначе для вас толку никакого от простого копи-паста не будет.

Comment: @SharpPythoneist вопросы идентичны, там надо распарсить HTML, тут надо распарсить HTML, если вы уже можете найти нужный div, то вам осталось взять от него InnerText и всё